# Push to github doesn't trigger jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured jenkins pipeline job which should be triggered by github push but it isn't.

1. I specified github project
2. https://github.com///
3. I checked GitHub hook
   trigger for GITScm polling And I run job manually.

I use ngrok so my localhost is visible. Important think is webhook is working fine because I tried do it with frystyle job and it was triggered. 
Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Try following settings mentioned @ https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-GitHubhooktriggerforGITScmpolling

Comment: Check the Github Hook Log of your job

Comment: @wijler I have the same issue, please let me know if you found a solution